# Directory searcher

Tags: c#, powershell

I initially wrote a script to generate Outlook signatures in PowerShell, and now I want to turn it into a C# program with extra features like template building and customization, etc.

The beauty of the initial script is that you simply pass a user name to it, and it does the rest. Pulls the info, creates a directory structure, spits out HTML etc.

What I'm having trouble with is pulling the info from AD in C#. I've been trying to get to this with the DirectoryServices namespace. I think I have a basic grasp of how it's supposed to work, and what it's supposed to do, but I keep getting errors as if I'm missing something important like a type conversion, or how to initialize the data to be usable inside the app.

Here's my code, and I don't know what's wrong with it:

```
Console.Write("What User do you want properties for?:");
string usr = Console.ReadLine();

DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("OU=users,DC=domain,DC=com");
DirectorySearcher find = new DirectorySearcher(dir, "(&(objectClass=User)(enabled=true)(SAMAccountName=" + usr + "))");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Surname");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("StreetAddress");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("City");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("State");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("PostalCode");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("OfficePhone");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("HomePhone");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Fax");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("EmailAddress");
find.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Pager");

Console.WriteLine(find.Filter);

SearchResult res = find.FindOne();
```

The error is around where I try to print to screen to ensure I have the right info. As shown here:

```
Console.Write(res);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Edit: Additional information.

The issue appears to be when executing

```
SearchResult res = find.findOne();
```

Also the actual error is

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unspecified Error

    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
    at System.DirectorySerivices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
    at System.DirecotryServices.DirecotrySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
    at System.DirecoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Also, compiler output. I was initially under the impression that this was because the machine I'm coding on isn't part of the domain I'm checking against, but I've also been running the executable on a machine that is.

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Unspecified error

  Source=System.DirectoryServices
  StackTrace:
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 36
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: You have to trying to print the object to the screen thats why the issue. Try to print it that objects properties.

Comment: If you update the question with the error that will be helpfull. Without error hard to imagine what is your issue.

Comment: As a note, you may want to add some sort of verification to ensure that the user inputs data that won't simply crash the program with strange errors.

Comment: Agreed, I will definitely work with try and catch blocks, but right now, I'm in the process of trying to ensure that I know how to make each piece of the project, then string it together, and then I'll worry about trying to make sure users don't to undesirable actions.

Comment: Just as a wild guess, could you try to build it as a 32-bit process and run it elevated? If that eliminates the error, we could think about why that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the protocol, server, and port in the path:

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://servername:port/OU=users,DC=domain,DC=com");
```

Comment: It resolved the initial issue, but it appears to have another issue. What is the format if you just want it to use any DC in the domain and specify the exact OU to search?

Comment: Try without the server:port, but keeping the protocol: "LDAP://OU=users,DC=domain,DC=com"

Comment: Got a different error, then tried it with instead of a server name I used my main FQDN. Then I think I'm at the point where the issue is only when I initialize my search result variable.